# Set TTL on Active Directory Group Membership using .NET DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Since the PAQ below, MemberTimeToLive was added to Active Directory

[Use .Net DirectoryServices to Set TTL on Active Directory Group Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894020/use-net-directoryservices-to-set-ttl-on-active-directory-group-membership)

I can add a member to a group with a TTL using Powershell, however, I want to do it via .NET DirectoryServices

```
$ttl = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 50
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SomeGroup" -Members "SomeUser" -MemberTime
ToLive $ttl
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

That feature isn't enabled in our domains, so I can't test this, but based on Figure 4 from [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2016/03/09/previewing-server-2016-tp4-temporary-group-memberships/), it looks like they just prefix the entry in the `member` attribute with `<TTL=time>,` where `time` is the time in seconds.

So if you already have a `DirectoryEntry` called `group`, and the `distinguishedName` of the account you want to add is called `memberDn`, then you can try this:

```
var ttl = TimeSpan.FromDays(5); //whatever time limit you want
group.Properties["member"].Add($"<TTL={ttl.TotalSeconds}>,{memberDn}");
group.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I have been testing so this confirms that what I have been trying is on the right track. Will test when I am onsite

Comment: Identical to my attempt except for I tried with static string. Tried it with a dynamic value just to ensure that format is correct by it says server unwilling to process request

Comment: You made sure to put a comma between the `<TTL=>` and the user DN? It's easy to miss. But I really don't know then. I can't test this myself.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I have created a choir web service to do on-behalf of me via Powershell. I believe validation on the DN is not yet extended to be aware of the <TTL=*> part

Comment: Well "server unwilling to process request" seems to mean that `DirectoryEntry` was ok with it, but the server didn't like something. So I could be wrong about the format. You could try doing it with PowerShell and then inspecting the group members with a tool that doesn't do any manipulation of the data, like LDP.exe, if you know how to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Format should be as shown below.

Closing arrow should be at the last.

```
group.Properties["member"].Add($"<TTL={ttl.TotalSeconds},{memberDn}**>**")
```